# How to bind jQuery live to entire window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to call some functions whenever the mouse is moved wherever it is located on the browser window. Currently, I am using:

```
$('html').live('mousemove', function(e) { ... }
```

which does not seem to work once the page scrolls down.

Is there a way to bind the `mousemove` event to the entire window?

```
$(window).live('mousemove', function(e) { ... }
```

results in nothing.

--

EDIT:

My code for the mouse function is as follows:

```
function mouseEvents() {



       // set up mouse movement
        $(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            if (window.imgLoaded) {
                var x = e.pageX/$(window).width()*504;
                var y = e.pageY/$(window).height()*504;
                console.log(y);
                drawKaleidoscope(window.ctx, window.img, x / 2, y / 2);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated... and you don't need it in this case, since `window` (or `document`) are **always** available. Just bind the event handler normally.

Comment: OK - Thank you everyone for the very prompt responses. I've updated to jQuery 1.7x, tried `$(window).bind(...)`, `$(document).bind(...)`, `$(document).on(...)` all of which provide similar results but I am still having the same problem where the mouse action is not called when scrolling down the document. I have a lot of absolute-positioned divs and I don't know why it doesn't call when scrolled to the bottom of the page: [View Screen Capture](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/396112/_IMG/_misc/document-bind-example.mov) < You can see that the action is not called when scrolled down for some reason...

Comment: @waffl ah you want it to trigger when you scroll as well? I'll edit my answer

Comment: I don't want the scroll to be the trigger, I just want the `mousemove` to affect the kaleidoscope the same way no matter where in the document you are. However, it just doesn't seem to 'trigger' when scrolled down for some reason.

Comment: @waffl In the video it's clearly moving when you move the mouse after you have scrolled down. If it's not moving right, you have to take account for it in your custom logic, but it's moving for sure.

Comment: @Esailija yes it is moving, but if you look at around 0:07s in the video, there are all these dead spots that don't exist in the upper part of the document for some reason? I've also set a `console.log()` to show if it is triggering, and in these 'dead zones', nothing is happening at all.

Comment: @waffl it's impossible to know why because that is affected by your custom code and html which you didn't post. You could be stopping propagation somewhere or not taking into account that the `epageY` coordinate will be very high and so on. It's impossible to guess.

Comment: @Esailija - Hi, I've edited with the code I'm using. My console is also showing a value of ~ 326 before it stops moving, so I doubt it is too high of a number. I've outlined elements and you can see it is for some reason not triggering when in this blank space on the bottom left. [View Screen Capture 2](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/396112/_IMG/_misc/document-bind-example-2.mov)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13464/discussion-between-waffl-and-esailija)

Comment: @waffl I am in [javascript](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).bind("mousemove", function(e) { ... } )`

<del>To trigger on scrolls as well (moving mousewheel doesn't trigger mousemove)</del>

<del>`$(document).bind("mousemove mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) { ... } )`</del>

<del>where `DOMMouseScroll` is firefox specific event for mousewheel.</del>

Comment: Thanks, in chat Esailija discovered it was a webkit bug and submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84233#c3). The temporary fix was to use jQuery to redeclare the height of the `html` element: `$("html").height($(document).height());`

Answer (score 0):

Please note:

.live is deprecated: see here: http://api.jquery.com/live/ (category deprecated)

You can try this:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) { ... }

**or**

$(document).live('mousemove', function(e) { ... }
```

Comment: I don't think `$(document).live` works... I think it only works with selectors.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/ hmm you are right! indeed bruv! Lmao seems to be working as a demo below by @Esailija

Comment: @FelixKling jQuery is forgiving here and it somehow works http://jsfiddle.net/TXPtt/

Comment: It calls `.on` with the empty string as selector (so it's equivalent to `$(document).on("mousemove", "", fn)`), which is ignored as if it didn't exist. I haven't tested with jQuery that doesn't support `.on` but I doubt it would work there.

Comment: @Esailija ++1 as you got something different bruv! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using .live? Live is for elements that have not been created yet (or elements that are dynamically added and removed).

`window` and `document` are there from the get go so just use `$(document).bind`.

If you are using jQuery 1.7+, use `$(document).on`.